# c pointers in string array

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to copy a char array into another char array using pointer arithmetic. It seems to be correct within the copy() but then I don't understand what happens after it gets to main. char a[] does not get the value of char b[] even if I called the function. Am I missing something? Hehehe

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void copy(char a[], char b[]){
        int *apoint = &a;
        printf("%d\n", apoint);
        printf("%d\n", &a);
        *apoint = b;
        printf("%d\n", *apoint);
        printf("%s\n", a);
        printf("%s\n", b);
    }

   int main(void){
        char a[100];
        char b[] = "bluhbluh";

        copy(a,b);
        printf("%d\n", a);
   }
```

Comment: are you able to successfully build this code?

Comment: It would be better to accept one of the helpful answers...

Comment: sorry!! :( It was the initial answer that followed my chain of thought. Didn't really know pointers don't work like this haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really not very meaningful C. I suspect it didn't even compile without warnings?

First you take the address of array `a`, then you take the address of array `b`, convert it to an integer (without a cast!), and then write that integer into the array `a`. Then, at the end of main, you try to print the char array as an integer.

Pointer arithmetic doesn't quite work like that. :)

I think you really mean to do something like this:

```
void copy(char a[], char b[]){
    char *ptr_a = a;
    char *ptr_b = b;

    while (*ptr_b != '\0') {
        *ptr_a = *ptr_b;
        ptr_a++;
        ptr_b++;
    }
    *ptr_a = '\0';
}

int main(void){
    char a[100];
    char b[] = "bluhbluh";

    copy(a,b);
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Of course, the proper way to do it is like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char a[100];
    char b[] = "bluhbluh";

    strncpy(a, b, 100);
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `strncpy()` doesn't put a `\0` if the limit is reached. So better call it with `99` (`sizeof a - 1`) and set `a[sizeof a-1] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

As ams points out in his/her answer, if you want a *copy* of the array, you need to duplicate each entry. Assuming you don't want to duplicate the array, but instead want `a` to point at `b`:

`apoint` doesn't do anything - it can't change the pointers of `a` or `b`. If you wanted to modify the address that `a` or `b` pointed to, you'd have to pass the address of them to your function. This won't work, however, as [arrays are not pointers](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html) - it's why you can't reassign arrays in C. You can modify pointers though - the following is an example of modifying a pointer to `a` to point at `b`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void redirect(char** a, char* b){
    *a = b;
}

int main(void){
    char a[100];
    char b[] = "bluhbluh";

    char* apt = a;
    redirect(&apt,b);
    printf("a=%s, b=%s", apt,b);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`apoint` should be a `char*`, don't you have a warning about this pointer assignment?
Moreover you're not iterating on all chars of the string...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the line `int *apoint = &a` is wrong, `&a` is pointer to pointer to char, while `apoint` is `int *`.  Don't you have compile errors?

Answer (score 0):

Method of copying the char is not good if you enable `-Wall` or `-Werror` in gcc you will see so many errors.

The thing you want, which is possible just by copying the pointers in main no need to call `copy (a,b);`

```
char *a;
char b[]="bluhbluh"
a=b;
```

now a started pointing to string "bluhbluh"

But I think that you dont want you want each and every character of `array b` to be copied into `array a`

you will have to do like this

```
void copy(char *a,char *b)
{
  while(*b!='\0')
    *a++=*b++;
 }

int main()
{
  char a[100];
  char b[]="bluhbluh";
  copy(a,b);
  printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some major errors in your code specially this line is incorrect `int *apoint = &a;` it should be `char* *apoint = &a;`

```
//Corrected Code:
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char a[], char b[]){
    char* *apoint = &a;
    printf("%d\n", apoint);
    printf("%d\n", &a);
    *apoint = b;
    printf("%d\n", *apoint);
    printf("%s\n", a);
    printf("%s\n", b);
}

int main(void){
    char a[100];
    char b[] = "bluhbluh";

    copy(a,b);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

This will solve the major code issues though I don’t think your copy function would still give your desire results as approach doesn’t seem very right.